# Is the inhalation of ammonia a possible health problem for bats in an artificial small volume winter roost?

Tags: ecology, bats

About 70 bats (Nyctalus noctula) spend their winter in an artificial small volume (0,050 cubic meters) winter roost located in the attic of a building. There is a single small exit to the outside directly from the roost. The roost has been cleaned before winter from bat droppings.

Is inhalated ammonia from bat droppings a potential health risk for them?